# Locating data files used by a C# program in a common location regardless of runtime context?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, file, path

A C# executable can reside in 3 different locations during it's life cycle when going from development to end user distribution:

- {project directory}\bin\Debug
- {project directory}\bin\Release
- {end user install directory}

My app has a web page and some ancillary files that I like to put in a sub-directory called *\video*, right beneath the directory that contains the executable.  What I really **don't** want to do is copy the sub-directory around between the 3 directories listed above.  In other words, obviously I don't want to end up with:

- {project directory}\bin\Debug\video
- {project directory}\bin\Release\video
- {end user install directory}\video

with the inherent re-copying every time the file in *\video* change.

What is a convenient overall strategy for keeping data files distributed with an application in a centralized directory, a directory that will be added to the *setup*  program when the application is distributed?  I'm hoping that I don't have to add *build* tasks to copy over the data files to the *\Debug* and *\Release* sub-directories every time the application is run in the Visual Studio 2012 IDE.  That leads to potential errors if I forget to copy a file during the *build* tasks and can create a mess if there a lot of files, especially large ones.

Is there a way to build the top level data path that detects conveniently each of the 3 different runtime contexts?  I don't mind if I have to wrap all *relative* data paths with a method that canonicalizes the data path when a *relative* path is passed to another method.  Here's an example using a fictitious method named *fixRelPath()* that would expand a relative path properly before passing it to a sample method named *openFile()*:

```
openFile(fixRelPath(".\\video\\temp.html"));
```

Comment: Did you try googling: get current run directory?

Comment: @ColeJohnson That will make an application fail if you run it with a different working directory than its installation directory.

Comment: @millimoose Not that way. I meant determine the executables location and strip the executable, not the current directory. My mistake

Comment: Have you considered setting the Video Files to type: Content and action: Copy always or Copy when newer? (You can find these options in the properties window)

Comment: @ColeJohnson That's the problem though. The location of the executable relative to the video files changes.

Comment: @millimoose IIRC `System.IO.Path.Combine` can handle relative directories

Comment: @ColeJohnson If I understand the question right, the point is *not* having to do that in the first place. More importantly, not having to try to figure out whether you need to.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your files in the AppData directory.

Per User:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

Shared:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
```

Comment: Isn't the app data directory per-user, and initially empty? I think the OP just wants a reliable way to specify "installation root" where a bunch of files are included during deployment. Analogously to how you can use `~/...` paths when working in ASP.NET to refer to files that are part of your webapp, without having to worry where the executables themselves are.

Comment: @millimoose - Fair enough.  Use `CommonApplicationData` instead.

Comment: Won't that also point to an *empty* directory under `C:\Users\` when the app is first run? If you have to copy stuff into that directory before you can use it you're just moving the original problem around - you still have to figure out where the "installation root" of the program is to find the source files.

Comment: @millimoose - He says he *doesn't* want the directory relative to the install directory.  He wants to avoid copying the files from debug, release, and user installation directories.

Comment: No, what the OP doesn't want is some directory, relative to the installation root, that changes depending on whether the program is run from within Visual Studio or after installation. What he wants is the installation root itself. I.e. when running under Visual Studio, this would be the project directory (the one that contains `bin\...`, where the `.exe` will be). When running "normally", he wants the directory the application was installed into - this time usually the one where the `.exe` will be. `CommonApplicationData` is neither of these.